# Cannot use button and link at the same time in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, single-page-application, react-router-dom

I'm working on a single page app with 4 different components. Each component should have submit button to save and send data inside the form.

However, when I use button to submit, it submits information but I also need to use react-router at the same time to switch between components.

The example below works for only submitting. I can pass data into state.
In addition to sending, it must also redirect to the other component to continue flow.

```
<Form onClick={handleSubmit}>

  <button>submit</button>
</Form>
```

I've also tried wrapping button with link, now I can switch between components but I can't submit and data to next component.

```
<Form onClick={handleSubmit}>
 <Link to ='/component'>
  <button>submit<button>
 </Link>
</Form>
```

**I need to find a way to use submit and react-router at the same time with single button.**

Thanks in advance for any valuable advice.

Comment: Have try to redirect to other component in your handleSubmit method?

Answer (score 3):

The declarative routing should be used here. Redirect to another route in handleSubmit method utilizing useHistory hook and `histoty.push()`. Link: https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Hooks

Answer (score 1):

you can use `useHistory` Hook in components

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/28397541)

Comment: `useHistory` is exactly only way to redirect user to another page via `onclick` event
 
in this case you must use `useHistory` and `history.push()` :)